# Are there rules for or against unusual or alternate weapon types?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, house-rules

In DnD 3.5 and Pathfinder, are there any provisions for characters wielding weapon types not on the given lists, like meat cleavers or swordcanes? Are those not allowed, do you use them as equivalent weapons (e.g. meat cleaver = dagger or shortsword, swordcane = just having a club and a shortsword), or can you tweak some stats to make them as new weapon types?

Comment: I'm almost certain that a sword-cane has been statted out as an Exotic weapon in at least one supplement. I'll try to find which when I get home. Though, of course, it would never be worth the feat.

Comment: I have it in the Ultimate Equipment actually, but as a martial weapon, surprise! Works more or less like a rapier, but more expensive and without the good critical range.

Comment: Ah, I don't have that book. Oh well, maybe DM will let me get away with the whole "rapier/club" thing.

Comment: With Pathfinder all that is always on the online SRD.  Go to http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons and voila, sword cane.

Comment: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/swordcane

Comment: I was actually planning to use the swordcane for a DnD character and the meat cleavers for a Pathfinder character, but ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both systems define "improvised weapons," found in the [weapons rules.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons)

> Sometimes objects not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in
>   combat. Because such objects are not designed for this use, any
>   creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be
>   nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with
>   that object. To determine the size category and appropriate damage for
>   an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential
>   to the weapon list to find a reasonable match.

Note there there are also some feats involving improvised weapons, such as [Improvised Weapon Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improvised-weapon-mastery-combat---final) and its prerequisites.

A meat cleaver would definitely be an improvised weapon, since it was not designed for combat but rather as a tool. I would probably consider it a hand-axe in terms of damage.

A sword-cane, however, would probably be an exotic weapon rather than an improvised one, and though there are no rules against it, since it is not defined in the rules, you would need to come up with its statistics with the approval of your DM.

Comment: I think that the key to easily mapping such unusual weapons into the campaign (the ones that aren't clearly improvised weapons) is to find a close match in the existing list and to make sure that you don't over-do the stats.  The weapons list is quite broad and there should, generally, be something quite close to what you're looking for (e.g. sword-cane=rapier?).

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking; we were guessing maybe meat cleaver = handaxe or shortsword minus piercing, and the swordcane would be something like just having a rapier/shortsword to represent the "sword" bit and a club for the "cane" bit.